# Get placeid for specific Latitude + Longitude or street address

Tags: vba, google-maps, excel, google-places-api

In Excel, I have both Street Address and Lat+Long and trying to get the PlaceID from Google Places API Web Service.  I research Geocoding API and Places API and did some VBA testing. The only way to get PlaceID for specific place is to do Text Search or Nearby Search.

Is there a way to get it from the address you have directly in VBA?
I've seen a demo website that using JavaScript to obtain the PlaceID, but don't know how to incorporate the JavaScript into Excel+VBA.

Comment: Sharing the demo website URL might have helped along with your best attempt code. [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you want [NearbySearch](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) (not sure why you don't think that gives you what you want):

> A Nearby Search lets you search for places within a specified area by keyword or type. A Nearby Search must always include a location, which can be specified in one of two ways:
>
> - a LatLngBounds.
> - a circular area defined as the combination of the location property — specifying the center of the circle as a LatLng object — and a radius, measured in meters.
>
> A Places Nearby search is initiated with a call to the PlacesService's nearbySearch() method, which will return an array of PlaceResult objects.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jph0oc1/)

code snippet:

```js
var map;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: {lat:40.689249,lng:-74.0445},
    zoom: 15
  });

  var request = {
      location: {lat:40.689249,lng:-74.0445},
    radius: 10
  };
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name+"<br>"+place.place_id);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
      document.getElementById('placeId').innerHTML = place.name+"<br>"+marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6)+"<br>"+place.place_id;
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div id="placeId"></div>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```